# How to exclude certain variables from POJO for logging

Tags: java, logging, pojo

I am using library from dependent component which includes pojos for the api requests. I need to log the request and response pojos for the api call. However i need to exclude certain elements from pojos as it cannot be logged. What are the options?

I looked at GSON and it does include @Exclude annotation. But since the pojos are from dependent libraries it cannot be modified to include any such annotations.

Comment: Can you extend the pojo and implement your own toString where you exclude the stuff you wanna exclude?

Comment: What do you mean by extend?

Comment: I thought like this

public class MyPojo extends Pojo {
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ""; //<—whatever, see if this can log your props
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that i'm undestand you correctly...

You simply want to log a GSON request and response, but as some elements cannot not be logged (what elements and why?) and you don't need them in you're request, you want to exclude them?

Beneath the @Exclude annotation there are other ways to exclude certain fields from serialization. You can look that up in the [corresponding documentation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization). For api documentation and exclusion of fields, have a look at [GSON javadoc](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0), especially GSONBuilder.setExclusionStrategy and ExclusionStrategy.

Comment: _what elements and why?_ For example, [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information) should not  be logged.  Do not make it easy for a hacker that has gained access to the web server.  Log files containing PII should not be shared/emailed either, since it could potentially expose info to unauthorized people.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I do not want to log pii info in the request. Looking for ways to do it as I cannot modify the Pojo

Comment: Ok, my question was obviously wrong. You should never log all connection parameters except a debugging environment!